# Recursive construstruction of JSON from text file

Tags: json, node.js, parsing, recursion

I have some difficulties to create a structured JSON from a text file. Here is an example of text file

```
BlocA
   value 1 param X
   value 2 param Y
   value 3 param Z

BlocB
   this is a line
   this is another line

BlocC foo
   1
   2
   3
BlocC bar
   something else
```

And the JSON I want is this :

```
{
"BlocA" : [
    "value 1 param X",
    "value 2 param Y",
    "value 3 param Z"
    ]
},
"BlocB" : [
    "this is a line",
    "this is another line"
    ]
},
"BlocC" : [
   {"foo" : [1,2,3]},
   {"bar" : ["something else"]}
 ]
}
```

In my text file, blocs always begin at the first character of a line and properties of a bloc are bellow and always begin with at least a space character.

Sometimes, bloc names are followed by a string (like "BlocC foo" and "BlocC bar") which became a sub document of BlocC array.

I'am using nodeJS to do that. I though doing this using recursion but it's a little bit too tricky for me.

Is there another way to accomplish this (with a parser or whatever)?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
const fs = require('fs')

let prop, subProp, json = {}

fs.readFile('data.txt', 'utf8', (err, data) => {

    data.split(/\r?\n/)
    .filter(line => line.search(/\S/) > -1)
    .reduce((obj, line) => {
        // array members
        if(line.search(/^\s+/) > -1) {

            subProp ? 
            obj[prop][obj[prop].length - 1][subProp].push(line.trim()) :
            obj[prop].push(line.trim())
        } else {
            // sub property
            if(line.search(/\s+/) > -1) {
                var props = line.split(/\s+/)
                prop = props[0].trim()
                subProp = props[1].trim()

                Array.isArray(obj[prop]) || (obj[prop] = [])
                obj[prop].push({
                    [subProp]: []
                })

            } else {
                prop = line.trim()
                subProp = null
                obj[prop] = []
            }
        }

        return obj
    }, {})

    console.log(json)

})
```